# Index weekends based on previous day

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I have a query for which my select statement looks like:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(p.date AS DATE) AS 'Date', 
    x.Month,
    x.Version,
    x.Value AS 'fcst',
     CASE WHEN isholiday = 0 
     THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x.Department, x.Month, p.isholiday ORDER BY p.date)
     ELSE 0
     END AS 'Index'
```

The output looks like this:

```
 Date       Month   Version fcst    isholiday   Index
2020-01-01  January 3plus9  3679    1            0
2020-01-02  January 3plus9  3679    0            1
2020-01-03  January 3plus9  3679    0            2
2020-01-04  January 3plus9  3679    1            0
2020-01-05  January 3plus9  3679    1            0
2020-01-06  January 3plus9  3679    0            3
2020-01-07  January 3plus9  3679    0            4
2020-01-08  January 3plus9  3679    0            5
2020-01-09  January 3plus9  3679    0            6
2020-01-10  January 3plus9  3679    0            7
2020-01-11  January 3plus9  3679    1            0
2020-01-12  January 3plus9  3679    1            0
2020-01-13  January 3plus9  3679    0            8
2020-01-14  January 3plus9  3679    0            9
2020-01-15  January 3plus9  3679    0            10
2020-01-16  January 3plus9  3679    0            11
2020-01-17  January 3plus9  3679    0            12
2020-01-18  January 3plus9  3679    1            0
2020-01-19  January 3plus9  3679    1            0
2020-01-20  January 3plus9  3679    0            13
```

The Index column is based on the 'isHoliday' column. At every point that isHoliday = 1, the Index shows 0, as shown in the case statement. Instead, if the day <>1, I need the Index value to show as the value of the Index above it.

For instance, on the rows where Date = Jan 4th and Jan 5th, the Index needs to show as 2. 
I have tried to make changes to the case statement, but have been unable to find a resolution.

Comment: the way I currently show indexes are based on business days only. On non-business days, I need to keep the same value as the previous business day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a cumulative count of `holiday = 0`:

```
select sum(case when isholiday = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by department, month order by date) as my_index
```

If `holiday` only takes two values, you can simplify this to:

```
select sum(1 - isholiday) over (partition by department, month order by date) as my_index
```